# How to return multiple json file in same route flask?

Tags: vue.js, flask, flask-restful

By using Axios, I can successfully fetch one JSON file returned from flask.
Now I have another JSON file that needs to be pass to the same route: /dashboard, is it possible to return several JSON files in one route?

ps. I'm a newbie in flask

Below are the codes:

```
    @app.route("/dashboard", methods= ['GET'])
    def key_index():
      try:
        key_index = db.sns.find({},{"_id":0}).sort([("datetime", -1)]).limit(1)
        return dumps(key_index)
      except Exception as e:
        return dumps({'error': str(e)})
```

```
   @app.route("/dashboard", methods= ['GET'])
   def sns_trend():
     try:
       trend = db.sns_2.find({})
       return dumps(trend)
     except Exception as e:
       return dumps({'error': str(e)})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a single letter json you can return 2 data
example

```
  @app.route("/dashboard", methods= ['GET'])
    def key_index():
      try:
        key_index = db.sns.find({},{"_id":0}).sort([("datetime", -1)]).limit(1)
        trend = db.sns_2.find({})
        return dumps({
            'key_index':key_index,
             'trend':trend
          })
      except Exception as e:
        return dumps({'error': str(e)})
```